# Sampling Question

Tags: statistics, sampling

[image]

Answer:

```
Sample 9604 people.
```

I don't even know to start this question, and how did the textbook get an exact number with no information on the total population?

Comment: $\sqrt{9604}=98$

Answer (score 1):

Using a normal population (suitable for large $n$ as contemplated here), a 95% confidence interval for the proportion $p$ of the population for the Candidate
is of the form
$$\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}},$$
where $\hat p = X/n,$ the *sample* proportion for the Candidate,
$\hat  E = \sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}$ is the estimated standard
error of the estimate $\hat p$, the standard error of $\hat p$ is 
$E = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}},$ and the margin error of the confidence
interval is $M = 1.96\hat E.$

You want to find $n$ large enough that $M = .01.$ Because we do not have
data it is best to use $M \approx 1.96E.$ Because we do not know $p$ we
consider the worst-case where $E$ is as large as possible, and that is
for $p = 1/2$. [The largest possible value of $p(1-p) = 1/4$ occurs
when $p = 1/2.]$

Thus we want to solve $1.96\sqrt{1/4n} = .01$ for $n.$ The solution is
$n = 9604.$

---

*Notes:* (1) A slight modification of this argument is widely used to plan
polls and to give rough margins of sampling error in reported results
of polls. If we use $1.96 \approx 2,$ then we get $M \approx 1/\sqrt{n}$ for a 95% confidence interval.
Thus a poll that uses random sampling with replacement of $n = 2500$ subjects should have a margin of error of at most $\pm 2\%.$ And a poll with $n = 1100$ 
respondents might have a margin of error for estimating $p$ with $M = 3\%$

(2) It is important to understand that the formulas used here apply only to
error that results from random sampling. If subjects are not randomly selected
from the population (e.g., people in favor of the Candidate are more
likely to be available), if people with some opinions are more likely to
answer than others, or if people do not tell pollsters what they really believe,
then these are not really probability issues and no probability formula can
account for the resulting biases and errors.

(3) If $p$ is very close to $0$ or $1$ then the formula discussed above may
overstate the required sample size.